# .htaccess redirect main domain to subdirectory can't access files issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When visiting the main domain "example.com" it should load files from a subfolder as I can't edit the main domain root document.

Structure:

```
public_html
    subfolder
        index.php
    anotherfolder
        image.png
    .htaccess
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subfolder/
RewriteRule (.*) /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

The code checks if the requested URL is not a file or directory and it doesn't contain `subfolder`, it redirects to the `subfolder`.

With this code I can access files from other folders like "example.com/anotherfolder/image.png" but when I try to visit "example.com" I get 403 forbidden.

I tried to remove these 2 lines that check it's not a directory or file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

I can access "example.com" but when I try to access the image in another folder, I get 404 not found.

How to solve this issue so that "example.com" loads files in "subfolder" and I can still access files in other folders?

Answer (score 0):

> but when I try to visit "example.com" I get 403 forbidden.

The 403 is because the rule is failing to rewrite requests for the root directory itself to the `/subfolder/` and you don't have a directory index document in the root directory.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> ```

Unless you need to access directories themselves (which is unusual) then simply remove the first *condition* that checks that it's not a directory (the root directory is a directory), not both conditions. You can then still access other files.

Otherwise, create an additional rule that rewrites just the root:

```
RewriteRule ^$ subfolder/ [L]
```

Note that the slash prefix on the *substitution* string is not required, in order to rewrite to a file-path, as opposed to a URL-path. (The same applies to your existing rule.)

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subfolder/
> ```

You should really *anchor* this regex so that it doesn't match `/subfolder/` at the *start* of the URL-path, not `subfolder/` anywhere in the URL-path. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
```

---

*Aside:*

> When visiting the main domain "example.com" it should load files from a subfolder **as I can't edit the main domain root document.**

A bit of a niggle, but if you could edit the "main document root" (to point to the "subfolder") then you wouldn't be able to access `/anotherfolder/image.png`, as in your example, since it would live outside of the publicly accessible document root.

So, if you are talking about editing the document root, then maybe *everything* should be in the "subfolder"? This makes the rewrite simpler, as you simply rewrite *everything* to the subfolder:

```
RewriteRule !^subfolder/ subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```